# Program still running after System.exit

Tags: java, swing

I'm a bit desperate over here. I Have this jFrame and I need to close after I press Escape. This is easily done by using keyTyped Event. In the keyTyped event I tried to use System.exit which closes the window, but the process is still running in the task manager (and in the netbeans, even If I run from the jar file, it is still running in the task manager).

I have tried dispose, setVisible(false) along with other things but nothing seems to work.

EDIT:

Code

```
public Sketch(int width, int height)
{
    sketch = new JFrame();
    area = new JLabel();

    sketch.setUndecorated(true);
    sketch.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    sketch.setSize(width, height);
    area.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);

    sketch.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    sketch.getContentPane().add(area);
    sketch.pack();

    sketch.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    sketch.setVisible(true);
    sketch.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    imageBGR = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
    imageGRAY = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);

    keyEvents();
    setup();

    Thread t = new Thread()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            running=true;
            while(running)
                draw();
        }
    };
    t.start();
}

    private void keyEvents()
{
    sketch.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getKeyChar()==KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE)
        {
            running=false;
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    });
}
```

NOTE: The setup function is a blank function that I override when extending this class.

EDIT2: SOLVED

I found out what I was doing wrong. It appears that in the class that I was extended this one, I was using a webcam. When I call the System.exit function the webcam led is turned off, so I thought I didn't need to properly release it, but it was in fact needed.

Comment: Do you have any processes still running? A Swing Timer, perhaps?

Comment: is the code small enough to post?

Comment: Updated with my code. I have a process running, but I ensure it closes. I've searched the web for over 2 hours and still couldn't find anything that worked.

Comment: Is running declared volatile?

Comment: It wasn't declared as volatile, but now that you mentioned it, I tested it as volatile and still doesn't work.

Comment: I found out what I was doing wrong. It appears that in the class that I was extended this one was using a webcam. When I call the System.exit function the webcam led is turned off, so I thought I didn't need to properly release it, but it was in fact needed.

Comment: `Don't use a KeyListener`. Swing was designed to be used with [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Answer (score 5):

The default behaviour when closing your frame is not to exit the program, but just to close the window. In order to exit the program you have to do:

```
jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

You can also do:

```
jFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
         public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
             System.exit(0);
         }
     });
```

Comment: Didn't work. The program still runs in the task manager :( I'm going to update with my code.

Comment: I added another option. Please try.

Comment: @benjamin.d, this is completely unrelated.  He is calling System.exit() directly.  See Hovercraft's answer.

Comment: I found out what I was doing wrong. It appears that in the class that I was extended this one was using a webcam. When I call the System.exit function the webcam led is turned off, so I thought I didn't need to properly release it, but it was in fact needed.

Comment: `setDefaultCloseOperation()` ... worked for my simple main that starts a SWING `JFrame`.  Some task was executing in the background (at least under Netbeans).  Using that tweak, exits right away when I click Exit.

Answer (score 3):

Your `running` variable needs to be declared `volatile`, and you need to set it to false at some point before closing.

Having said that, this code looks dangerous and bad:

```
Thread t = new Thread()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        running=true;
        while(running)
            draw();
    }
};
t.start();
```

You've no `Thread.sleep(...)` within there, so it risks hogging the CPU, and as it looks like you're trying to modify Swing state off of the Swing event thread, you're in danger of intermittent thread failure. This suggests to me that you want to use a Swing Timer instead.

---

Note that for more complete help, consider posting a minimal code example that demonstrates your problem, an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). This will allow us to run your code and modify it and perhaps even correct it.  Please read the link before replying as it supplies many important details on the SSCCE requirements.

Comment: I found out what I was doing wrong. It appears that in the class that I was extended this one was using a webcam. When I call the System.exit function the webcam led is turned off, so I thought I didn't need to properly release it, but it was in fact needed.

Comment: @RicardoAlves: thank you for the update. But I again stand by my recommendation about taking care to update Swing matters only in the Swing thread.

Comment: @RicardoAlves, your comment is not describing the relevant issue with the code execution system. What i mean that you should first understand why your program is halting exit even after you are exiting. Forget about your webcam. First know the rules to stop execution of a thread for some time and awake it; and the relation of main thread with child thread. Main thread will only exit when there is no child thread is running other than the `Daemon` thread.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, +1 for targeting the `while` loop issue.

Comment: I'm assuring the Thread exits, as I turn the running flag off before the system.exit() function. Isn't that enough?